# $http get does not throw success or error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wcf, angularjs-1.6

The below is the declaration of WCF RESTful service for GET

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate= "MemberSearch/{MemberName}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string MemberSearch(string MemberName);
```

The below is the RESTful Service I have created

```
public string MemberSearch(string MemberName)
    {
        string MemberId = string.Empty;
        string strSqlConn = string.Empty;

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlCon"].ConnectionString);
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("Select MemberId From Member Where MemberName Like '%" + MemberName + "%'");
        sqlCom.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;

        SqlDataReader rd = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            MemberId = Convert.ToString(rd["MemberId"]);
        }
        return MemberId;
    }
```

The below is the data in the table

```
MemberId MemberName
1   John        
2   Mike        
3   Gracy       
4   Smith
```

The below is the calling code in AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("main", function ($scope, $http) {
var MemberName = "Jo";

$scope.keyword = '';

$scope.GetAllData = function () {

    $http.get('http://localhost/MemberEligibilityDemo/MemberService.svc/MemberSearch/' + MemberName)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Details = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<br />status: " + status +
                "<br />headers: " + jsonFilter(header) +
                "<br />config: " + jsonFilter(config);
        });
};
});
```

The Angular code does not either come into success or error for this

The URLs are as below

```
http://localhost/MemberEligibilityDemo/MemberService.svc/MemberSearch/
```

Calling location is as follows

```
http://localhost/Caller
```

The result from WCF RESTful service is as below

```
{"MemberSearchResult":"1"}
```

**EDIT**

The calling location is as below

```
<body ng-app="app">
<table id="tblContainer" ng-controller="main">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="DisplayDetails" value="Display Details" ng-click="GetAllData()"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p ng-bind="ResponseDetails"></p>
            {{ResponseDetails}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why it is not executing either success or error in AngularJS code.

Comment: There is no evidence of where you ever call `$scope.GetAllData()`. Could you add that? We also can't see evidence that the URL path would be appropriate here from the WCF side.

Comment: Also, AngularJS version? `.success()` isn't valid as of 1.6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Please look up how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: @Brian Yes. I am using AngularJS version 1.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `$http` function to this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/MemberEligibilityDemo/MemberService.svc/MemberSearch/' + MemberName)
    .then(function(resp) {
        $scope.Details = resp.data;
    }, function(err) {
        var data = err.data;
        var status = err.status;
        var header = err.header;
        var config = err.config;
        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
            "<br />status: " + status +
            "<br />headers: " + jsonFilter(header) +
            "<br />config: " + jsonFilter(config);

    });
```

> My answer assumes that you have a button or link that is calling this from your UI.

I am also guessing that you are iterating over a list of users (`ng-repeat`), and would suggest changing your method to what is below, and calling like this: `GetAllData(memberId)`.

```
$scope.GetAllData = function (memberId) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/MemberEligibilityDemo/MemberService.svc/MemberSearch/' + memberId)
    // abbreviated
}
```

Comment: With the above answer, I am getting `then` executed. It is returning object and how can I deserialize it?

Comment: That depends on what is coming back..it should be a JSON object. If it has a property `name`, it would be `resp.name`, etc..